# How to add markers to map from rest-api?

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin.ios, xamarin, google-maps-sdk-ios

I'm using the Google Maps component inside my Xamarin.iOS project. I am grabbing the json from my request, parsing it, tries to add each array on response as a marker on the `mapView`. When I build my application, I get no error message, the app runs as it should. But there's no markers on my map.

**MapController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using MonoTouch.Foundation;
using MonoTouch.UIKit;
using System.Net;
using System.Json;
using System.IO;
using Google.Maps;
using MonoTouch.CoreLocation;

namespace News
{
        public partial class MapController : UIViewController
        {

                MapView mapView;

                public MapController () : base ("MapController", null)
                {
                        Title = "Karta";
                }

                public override void ViewDidLoad ()
                {
                        base.ViewDidLoad ();
                        this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.White;
                        this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.SetTitleTextAttributes (new UITextAttributes { TextColor = UIColor.White });
                        this.NavigationController.NavigationBar.BarTintColor = UIColor.Orange;

                        var camera = CameraPosition.FromCamera (
                                latitude: 0.0,
                                longitude: 0.0,
                                zoom: 6
                        );

                        mapView = MapView.FromCamera (RectangleF.Empty, camera);

                        try {
                                var request = WebRequest.Create("http://www.example.com");
                                var response = request.GetResponse ();
                                using(var stream = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream())){
                                        var json = stream.ReadToEnd ();
                                        var jsonVal = JsonValue.Parse (json);                          
                                        for(var i=0; i<jsonVal["result"].Count; i++){
                                                //CLLocationCoordinate2D coord = new CLLocationCoordinate2D();
                                                InvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
                                                        // manipulate UI controls
                                                        var marker = new Marker () {
                                                                Title = jsonVal["result"][i]["title"],
                                                                Snippet = jsonVal["result"][i]["address"],
                                                                Position = new CLLocationCoordinate2D (jsonVal["result"][i]["lat"],jsonVal["result"][i]["lon"])
                                                        };
                                                        marker.Map = mapView;
                                                });
                                        }
                                };
                                response.Close ();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                                //
                        }
                        mapView.StartRendering ();
                        View = mapView;
                }

                public override void ViewWillAppear (bool animated)
                {
                        base.ViewWillAppear (animated);
                }

                public override void ViewWillDisappear (bool animated)
                {      
                        mapView.StopRendering ();
                        base.ViewWillDisappear (animated);
                }
        }
}
```

Why it that so?

Comment: Do you have a sample response? I built a simple app using largely everything you did, and I was able to iteratively add pins to my map.

Comment: @TimSneed Here's a gist https://gist.github.com/jackbillstrom/75be6339efc1e54f1ce2

Comment: I updated the gist. I noticed you use a xib, so I am curious if everything is set up correctly there. I also noticed you set the camera to 0,0 which is off the coast of Africa. Are you still not seeing pins when you go to the town Sundsvall on the map?

Comment: The reason I've set the camera to 0,0 is due to my lack of knowlage. Still trying to get the users location.

I tried out your code. It works, i changed the syntax to grab the data from an API with no luck..

Comment: Hmm, when you set a breakpoint, do you get data back correctly from your service? you could use HttpClient, that seems a bit more en vogue these days.  using (var httpClient = new HttpClient()){ client.Get("website"); //then read the stream }

Comment: In the same project I have about four other ViewControllers which uses the WebRequest, fully working.

I can't seem to output the response to the console either. 
If would really help if you could try it out yourself. Here's the API-url:

http://www.unikabutiker.nu/api/?function=searchByName&key=kT6zAOpNk21f9UhhNWzVrK8fHjvl22K2imF1aRkvN9aScUOK6v&name=Sundsvall

Comment: If you can zip this and send what you have I will take a look at this later today?  If so, can you email me the solution.  My contact details are on my Profile.

Comment: @Pete I have now sent you the project file compressed into a .tar.gz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running your example you had a blocking call.

In your `\Controller\Maps\MapControler.cs`

**change:-**

```
public override void LoadView()
```

**to:-**

```
public async override void LoadView()
```

and also **change:-**

```
Task.Run(async() => await StageTheView());
```

**to:-**

```
await StageTheView();
```

It will then run, and display your markers.

Let me know if you want me to send back the solution if your still experiencing any difficulty?

Comment: Just as a comment, I am pretty sure it is considered bad practice to have an async void outside of a top level event handler.

Comment: This was a fix to **your** code that @Jack sent me to get this working as it wasn't working for him.  I did not write this from the ground up.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment with the api, I was able to load data; try something like this.

```
public override void LoadView ()
    {
        base.LoadView ();

        CameraPosition camera = CameraPosition.FromCamera (62.3909145, 17.3098496, 15);

        mapView = MapView.FromCamera (RectangleF.Empty, camera);
        mapView.MyLocationEnabled = true;

        Task.Run(async () => await StageTheView());

        View = mapView;
    }

    private async Task StageTheView()
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var result = await client.GetAsync("http://www.unikabutiker.nu/api/?function=searchByName&key=kT6zAOpNk21f9UhhNWzVrK8fHjvl22K2imF1aRkvN9aScUOK6v&name=Sundsvall");
            var s = "";
            using (var reader = new StreamReader(await result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()))
            {
                s = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }

            var jsonVal = JsonValue.Parse(s);                          
            for (var i = 0; i < jsonVal["result"].Count; i++)
            {
                // manipulate UI controls
                var marker = new Marker()
                {
                    Title = jsonVal["result"][i]["title"],
                    Snippet = jsonVal["result"][i]["adress"],
                    Position = new CLLocationCoordinate2D(jsonVal["result"][i]["lat"], jsonVal["result"][i]["lng"])
                };
                marker.Map = mapView;
            }
        }
    }
```

You will have to add a reference to System.Threading.Tasks and System.Net.Http

Comment: Put your xib in the gist. There must be something going on there.

Comment: Her's my .xib https://gist.github.com/jackbillstrom/cf482349db86ec43f837

I'm so thankful that you're assisting Tim!